# How can parse the NpgsqlDataReader objects?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

write this simple cpde to execute PostgreSQL function:

```
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    Result += MacAddr.Trim() + "^&" + converter.shamsi(dr[0].ToString()) + "^&" + converter.shamsi(dr[1].ToString())
                            + "^&" + "" + "^&" + dr[3].ToString() + "^&" + "Fiber" + "\r\n";
                }
```

but when i debug up code:

[image]

how can parse the dr[0]?

Comment: dr[0] is a datetime object and does not need to be parsed.  So DateTime date = (DateTime)dr[0];

Comment: @jdweng get Specified cast is not valid error

Comment: What about Date date = DateTime.Parse(dr[0].ToString());  It is possible your machine is usikng a different culture.  Does following work : DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("6/11/2019 10:51:43 AM");

Comment: @jdweng ok ,so how can parse dr[0][3]?

Comment: I was wrong.  It is not two dimensional.  It thought initially it was a DataRow from a table and not a result from ExecuteReader().